# Google Analytics on Google Documents

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace, google-analytics

I wanted to use Analytics on Google documents. There doesn't seem to be an easy way of doing this. Even in the new UI.

It's been only 24 hours since I tried this, and I know that it takes more to get statistics, but since the on the tracking status, it says **Tracking not installed**, thus, I'm sure that something mid-way might have gone wrong.

Here is what I did.

Google Analytics Page :

1. Create New Account

   ```
   [NAME : DOCUMENTS] 
   [URL : https://docs.google.com]
   ```
2. I got a page with the Web Property Id as `UA-2xxxxxxxx-x`

On the Google Docs page :

1. `Document Settings` -> `Editing` -> `Document Tracking` -> put the tracking code.
2. Create a new test document, made it public.

Now one inconsistency, when opened the document source, it did not have seem to have the analytics script.

Answer (score 1):

I think with recent changes to Google docs this feature is in a weird state. Anyway it was supposed to work only for your published docs. The ones that get published as static webpages. There's no way to really track the usage of your spreadsheet through the interface.

You can always see the history to check the changes users did.